# iOSの申請でエラー。[The u option must have a non-empty value]

Tags: ios, monaca, xcode, macos

お世話になっております。
このたびアプリをアップデートしようとしたのですが
下記のエラーが赤字で発生しアップロードすることができません。

```
The u option must have a non-empty value
The password option must have a non-empty value
```

昨日から発生しているので困っております。
どのように対処すればよろしいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

環境
OS X El Capitan(10.11)
Xcode(7.0.1)
Application Loader(3.2)

---

**追記**
今回申請しようとしているものはMonacaを使用してビルドしております。
リリース用のZIPファイルになっているものなのでXcodeから直接アップロードは考えておりません。
`Organizer`を使用してではなく`Application Loader`を使用してアップロード申請を行いたいです。

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33271042/error-when-uploading-to-itunesconnect オーガナイザーの Upload to App Store ボタンでできましたよ。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appleのカスタマーサポートとやり取りしながら検証していたのですが、
その際に`Application Loaderのバージョン`に思い至りダウングレードしました。
[Application Loader 3.0](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_3.0.dmg)を使用してアップロードしたところすんなりアップロードが出来ました。
新しい3.2のApplicationLoaderだと何かしらの問題があるのかもしれません。